# React tuto tictactoe game - who's the winner - return null inside a for loop

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, if-statement, return, tic-tac-toe

In the tuto of React.dev, i get confused  when it comes to tell who is the winner : [tutorial tictactoe - part who's the winner](https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe#declaring-a-winner)

I can't get `return winner` if i put `return null` inside the for loop instead of putting it outside, it keeps returning `null`.

From the `line 59` of `App.js` in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tictactoe-game-react-who-is-the-winner-gqs2mu)

```
function theWinner(squares) {
 const lists = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

 for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
   const [a, b, c] = lists[i];
   if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
     return squares[a];
    }else{
     return null ; 
    }
   }
 }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop will always exit on its first iteration. This is obviously not what you want.

While you can stop looking further when you have found a winning line, you should *continue* looking further when the current 3 cells do *not* represent a win. So in that case doing a `return` is premature. You cannot know whether there will be a win elsewhere or not. For that you need to make *all* iterations of the loop, and only after you have verified all, you can conclude that there are no winning lines.

So:

```
function theWinner(squares) {
  const lists = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lists[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null; // <-- only now we can know there was no win.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I do a little test myself :
`function test (arr){const lists = [[1,2,3],[2,2,3], [4,5,8]]; 

  for(let i = 0; i<lists.length; i++){

const [a, b, c] = lists[i]; if(a ===arr[0] && b===arr[1] && c===arr[2])
{return console.log('equal'); }else{return console.log('not equal'); }}}
let s = [4,5,8];
test(s);`
It only works when i give an array equals to the first item of `const lists`, meaning the for...loop runs just once for all. If i give an array equals to the second or third item of `const lists`, the code stop working like u said